# How do I change the default prompt from "#" to ">"?

Tags: linux, shell, prompt

How can I change the default prompt in Linux (red-hat 5.4) from "#" to ">"?
example

```
[root@moon11 root]#
```

to

```
[root@moon11 root]>
```

Comment: Note that it is conventional to keep a `#` in the prompt to remind you that you are playing with fire because you have root privileges and any mistakes can completely wreck the machine.  You should always do as little as possible while running as root.

Answer (score 6):

This is defined in your ~/.bashrc file in the variables PS1 and PS2.
Find their values and change # to > .
Take a look at [bash variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) and [controlling the prompt](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Printing-a-Prompt.html).

EDIT:

In my ~/.bashrc file if I change

```
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

to

```
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\> '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\> '
```

it does the job.

Comment: see edit in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

My answer: **Don't do it !**

The fact root's prompt is by default `#` has a very useful side effect. It happens from time to time that people logged as root copy and paste what is on their screen by error. The default prompt makes that operation less risky by preventing the pasted commands to be executed again.

If you change your prompt to `>`, instead of commenting out the commands, that would run your prompt prefix as a command (likely a not found one) but redirect anyway its output to what used to be the command to execute, essentially blanking the file. Should you gave a file name that happens to be in the current directory (eg: passwd) or the full path of a sensitive binary and you are in serious trouble.

Comment: Nice info! However, this should probably be a comment!

Comment: Agreed. I hesitated but finally opted for a reply for it to have a better visibility than a mere comment. I once had to investigate a bricked OS, was first surprised to see plenty of commands no more giving any output and finally found the root cause in root's history ...

Comment: While I do agree with everything you say, it's still not an answer... Please do post it as a comment next time. The OP will receive a notification of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind the other answers' recommendation to **avoid reducing root's visibility**, here's a useful guide to bash prompt editing that a college associate made many years ago: [Bash Prompt HowTo](http://www.gilesorr.com/bashprompt/howto/)