# How can I change the text after the @-sign in my terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, bash-scripting

How can I change the text after the @-sign? I don't know what it means.

[image]

It says `DESKTOP-HMEEP40`.

Comment: DESKTOP-HMEEP40 is the computer name of terminal you're logged into. To change it, change your computer name. Can't tell which OS you're on from the picture alone.

Comment: @PatrickJørgensen - It would be better to change `PS1`, as per Kamil Maciorowski's deleted answer.

Answer (score 4):

This `DESKTOP-HMEEP40` string you ask about is probably the hostname retrieved by `\h` in `$PS1`. Ways to change it differ between OS-es/distros. With `systemd` you do it by invoking

```
hostnamectl set-hostname new_name_here
```

---

The whole `root@…` string is defined by `PS1` shell variable:

> `PS1`
>
> Each time an interactive shell is ready to read a command, the value of this variable shall be subjected to parameter expansion and written to standard error. […]

<sub>([source](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_03))</sub>

Run `printf '%s\n' "$PS1"` to see what the variable is in your case. It probably contains some special strings like `\u`, `\h`. The relevant fragment of Bash Reference Manual is [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt). You can change `PS1` like (almost) any other variable:

```
PS1='whatever '
```

To make a permanent change define the variable in your `.bashrc` file.

[This search result](https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D+ps1) may lead you to some interesting examples.

Comment: Great answer to a somewhat weak question, but I'm wondering if this hasn't already been answered somewhere else here? We also have: https://superuser.com/questions/368218/how-do-i-change-the-default-prompt-from-to and https://superuser.com/questions/370170/how-can-i-make-my-terminals-command-prompt-shorter-to-increase-line-realestate

Answer (score 1):

**`root@DESKTOP-HMEEP40:~#`** *(Prompt variable likely resembles: `\u@\h:\w\$`)*

- **`root`:** username
- **`DESKTOP-HMEP40`:** hostname
- **`~`:** current directory
- **`#`:** typically specifies root/superuser, whereas **`$`** is typically for all other accounts

The `PS1`/`prompt` variable is what determines the format of shell prompt, and it's format and layout depends on the OS and shell being utilized.  It's normally found in the shell's config file or the user's profile config.

- **Examples:**

  - **Shell Config:** `~/.bashrc` for bash, `~/.cshrc` for csh/tcsh, etc.
  - **User Profile:** `~/.profile` or `/etc/profile`, `profile.ps1`, etc.
- **Helpful links:**

  - [HowTo: Customize BASH Shell Prompt](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)
  - [HowTo: Colorize BASH Shell Prompt](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/)

**Syntax of the `PS1`/`prompt` variable will vary with each shell & OS:**

- **[ash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ash) / [dash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dash)** (BusyBox)

  - ***w/o color***

    ```
    export PS1='\u@\h \w\$ '
    ```

    - **`\u`:** username
    - **`\h`:** hostname
    - **`\w`:** working directory
    - **`\$`:** promptchars shell variable
  - ***w/ color***

    ```
    export PS1='[\[\033[34m\]\u\[\033[0m\]\[\033[32m\]@\[\033[0m\]\[\033[34m\]\h\[\033[0m\]] \[\033[34m\]\w\[\033[0m\] \[\033[32m\]\$\[\033[0m\] '
    ```
- **[bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):** (Ubuntu)

  - ***w/o color***

    ```
    PS1='[${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h]:\w\$ '
    ```

    - **`\u`:** username
    - **`\h`:** hostname
    - **`\w`:** working directory
    - **`\$`:** promptchars shell variable
  - ***w/ color***

    ```
    PS1='[${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[38;5;039m\]\u\[\033[00m\]\[\033[38;5;154m\]@\[\033[00m\]\[\033[38;5;039m\]uvm\[\033[00m\]] \[\033[38;5;039m\]\w\[\033[00m\] \[\033[38;5;154m\]\$\[\033[00m\] '
    ```
- **[powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-6):** (Microsoft)

  - ***w/o color***

    ```powershell
    Function set-prompt {
      "$ESC[$($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('$' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) $ESC[0m"
    }
    ```
  - ***w/ color***

    ```powershell
    Function set-prompt {
      Param (
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [ValidateSet("Default","Test")]
        $Action
      )

      switch ($Action) {

        "Default" {
          Function global:prompt {
            if (test-path variable:/PSDebugContext) { '[DBG]: ' }
              write-host " "
              write-host ("$ESC[48;2;40;40;40m$ESC[38;2;170;210;0m$(Get-Location) $ESC[0m $ESC[0m")

            if ( $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle -match "Administrator" ) {
              $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'Red'
              $(if ($nestedpromptlevel -ge 1) {
                write-host ('PS $$ ') -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewLine
              } else {
                write-host ('PS $ ') -ForegroundColor Red -NoNewLine
              })

            } else {
              $(if ($nestedpromptlevel -ge 1) {
                write-host ('PS $$ ') -ForegroundColor Blue -NoNewLine
              } else {
                write-host ('PS $ ') -ForegroundColor Blue -NoNewLine
              })
            }

            return " "
          }
        }
      }
    }

    set-prompt Default
    ```
- **[tcsh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)** (BSD)

  - ***w/o color***

    ```bash
    set prompt = "%N@%m:%~ %# "
    ```

    - **`%N`:** effective username
    - **`%m`:** hostname
    - **`%~`:** working directory
    - **`%#`:** promptchars shell variable
  - ***w/ color:***

    ```bash
    set prompt = "[%{\033[34m%}%N%{\033[0m%}%{\033[32m%}@%{\033[0m%}%{\033[34m%}%m%{\033[0m%}] %{\033[34m%}%~%{\033[0m%}%{\033[32m%}#%{\033[0m%} "
    ```