# I can not su or sudo -i as root, and also can not ssh as root.But they all can work with other users

Tags: linux, ssh, root, sudo, su

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlkBe.png)

### Doesn't work as root

`sudo -i` and `su` can not work as root.

```
[atguigu@hadoop103 ~]$ sudo -i
[atguigu@hadoop103 ~]$ su
Password:
```

`ssh` login as root and it was closed instantly.

```
[atguigu@hadoop103 ~]$ ssh root@hadoop103
root@hadoop103's password: 
Last login: Mon Jan 18 18:37:57 2021
Connection to hadoop103 closed.
```

### But work as other users

but it can `su` or `ssh` as other users.

```
[atguigu@hadoop103 ~]$ ssh atguigu@hadoop103
Last login: Mon Jan 18 17:38:44 2021 from xxx
```

`su` other user.

```
[atguigu@hadoop103 ~]$ su atguigu
Password: 
[atguigu@hadoop103 ~]$ exit
exit
[atguigu@hadoop103 ~]$
```

---

My `/etc/sudoers` has root.It likes.

```
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
atguigu   ALL=(ALL)     NOPASSWD:ALL
```

`/etc/passwd` with root fields likes

```
[~]$ cat /etc/passwd | grep root
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
```

ps: My environment is CentOS7.

Comment: Please put all explanation in your question instead of linking to a question. Also, this question is off-topic here, as this is not related to programming

Comment: @NicoHaase sorry,I am new for stackoverflow. I have changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/etc/passwd` specifies `/bin/bash` as the command interpreter for root. If it was `/sbin/nologin` or `/bin/false/`, the symptoms would be the same. It's not the case though.

Run `sudo /bin/bash -x`. You will probably see `+ exit`. One of the startups scripts for root's Bash contains `exit` and therefore the shell exits.

`sudo /bin/bash --norc` should skip these files. It should give you an elevated shell.

The next step is to find this `exit` that prevents you from starting the shell normally; and remove it. It's probably in `.bashrc` in the home directory of root user (your `/etc/passwd` states the home directory is `/root`, so edit `/root/.bashrc`). There's also `/etc/bash.bashrc` but `exit` there would affects all users, so we can rule it out.

Note if you're not the only admin then it may be another admin placed `exit` in root's `.bashrc` deliberately to prevent users from using the root's shell. With `sudo` access you are able to revert this, make sure you're not interfering with somebody else's general idea on how things should work though.

Comment: thanks so much. you're awesome. 
I deleted the `/root/.bashrc` file containing the exit content.
One little confusion.The interactive shell switch to `bash-4.2# ` instead of `[root@xxx ~]`, It can be changed?

Comment: Are you still there? Can you do me the last favor?

Comment: @KnechtJoseph You need to set `PS1`. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1385089/432690). Check what it is for your regular user and set similarly for root.

Comment: Thanks! It's completely restored(lol). I want to upvote this answer but I dont have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

SSH as root is disabled by default on CentOS (and rightly so). Your ability to `sudo` is controlled by `/etc/sudoers` so most likely your user and group is not mentioned there.

Comment: It seems not this problem. My `/etc/sudoers` likes `root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL`
,`atguigu   ALL=(ALL)     NOPASSWD:ALL`